# Python loop of strings - why the 'none' comes?

Tags: python, for-loop, parallels

I have a strange question when using python loop. It may be easy but strange to me. Say if I have a list of strings:

```
seqs=['AA', 'AT']
```

Then I want to print out elements in the list. One way (method 1) is to use for loop:

```
for seq in seqs:
    print seq
```

Which works fine. Meanwhile, I define a 'print' function (method 2) to print:

```
def print0(s):
    print s

[print0(s) for s in seqs]
```

If I use the 'print0' function to print out values, this is the output:

```
AA
AT
[None, None]
```

I want to know why here comes two 'None' values, since these two values doesn't come when I use the method 1? I want to do the for loop by using paralleling technic, but with the 
'None' value, `delayed` function from `joblib` package can't work. Thanks.
Update: if I want do it parallel:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(print0)(seq) for seq in seqs)
```

It will give an error message:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Comment: ... Because you don't return anything...

Comment: both snippets are semantically different: one is just a for-loop with print statement while the other, you are creating a list with list-comprehension using a function that returns nothing (none)

Comment: In addition to what has been proposed in the answers, if you do not want to see the `None`s, discard the value of the expression: `_=[print0(s) for s in seqs]`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using the interactive interpreter, which by default prints the `repr()` for any object returned to the top level, you see a list of `None` objects, which is what got returned from the calls of your `print0` function. This is why it's not good practice to create a list just for its side effects, in addition to the fact that all of those objects are stored in memory (although there's only one `None` object, and that list will be garbage-collected as soon as you return something else to the top level - until then, it's stored in the special variable `_`).

You'll recognize how the interpreter displays the `repr()` of any object returned to the top level:

```
>>> 'hello'
'hello'
```

And it makes sense that the following literal list is displayed:

```
>>> [print()]

[None]
```

And the same for a comprehension:

```
>>> [print(num) for num in range(3)]
0
1
2
[None, None, None]
```

But it's better to use an ordinary loop. One-liners are fun, but not always ideal.

```
>>> for num in range(3):
...     print(num)
...
0
1
2
```

Note that you can get odd results if a function prints one thing and returns another:

```
>>> def f():
...     print(1)
...     return 2
...
>>> [f() for num in range(3)]
1
1
1
[2, 2, 2]
>>> for num in range(3):
...     f()
...
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

This is a demonstration of "side-effects." Try to avoid code that makes changes in two different places at once (in this case, the interactive interpreter's displayed results and the local actions of a function).

Comment: None is a singleton, as you said, so I don't understand your point about the list / memory footprint thing.

Comment: This is a good answer because of how in-depth it is, but it fails to clear up any confusion the poster has. I don't think they're interested in garbage collection or good list practices.

Comment: @CharlesAddis - If they use a function that returns some non-singleton data they're not interested in, that'll use O(n) memory. It's just another reason to write a proper loop instead of a comprehension when you don't care about the result.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson - I've added some more explanation.

Comment: removed the downvote, as the answer has been edited and is a good answer... but even if the return a list of strings or integers the memory footprint is NOT O(n) -- please check the output of `for _ in comprehension: print id(_)` -- you'll see that strings are interned and python only stores one instance of each unique integer @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `[print0(s) for s in seqs]` is a [List Comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

It will call `print0(s)` for every element in `seq` and put the result into a list. Because `print0` returns nothing, you get a list of 2 `None`s.

Answer (score 1):

*I see such questions so often, there should be some ultimate answer to them all, which automatically triggers whenever `print` and `None` are both present in a single question...*

While the answer to the question itself is trivial, what, I think, you need to really understand is a difference between a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) and a *return value*. For example:

```
a = 10
def three(x):
    global a
    a += x #side effect
    print x #side effect
    return 3 #returning
```

The value our `three()` function returns is 3. It also has two side effects: modifying a global variable `a` and printing. Those are called side effects because they modify something outside of the function: the `a` variable and the screen state, respectively.

In your example:

```
def print0(s):
    print s
```

there's no explicit return value, only a side effect (printing). In other words, it prints something on the screen and then *returns nothing*. That *nothing* is called `None` in Python. If you call it like this:

```
a = print0(3)
```

it prints 3 into the console. But what is the value of `a` now?

```
>>> print a
None
```

Now to the list comprehension. It is a concept borrowed from functional programming (Lisp, etc.) where it's called `map`. There's still `map` function in Python, so the following two lines are equivalent:

```
[print0(s) for s in seqs]
map(print0, seqs)
```

What they both do is taking the elements of the input list (`seqs`), one by one, applying the function (`print0`) to each of them and putting the results (return values), one by one, into the output list, which they return. Each time they call your `print0` function, it prints its argument `s` on the screen (a side effect) and then returns nothing (`None`), which is put into the output list by list comprehension or `map`. If you do it in the Python interactive console, that result appears in the output (`[None, None]`), if not - it is still produced by the interpreter and immediately discarded, unless you pass it as an argument to another statement. Which leads us to your final line of code and the `TypeError` message. You pass your function to another function, which expects a string, it doesn't care about the side effects your function may produce. The context is not completely clear to me, but you probably should define your function like this:

```
def print0(s):
    return str(s)
```

Now, instead of printing `s` on the screen, it converts it to `string` and then *returns* it. Note that if you call them inside the interactive interpreter just like `print0(s)`, it appears they produce the same effect, which may be confusing. However, if you do `a = print0(s)` you will see that `a` is different. In some languages the last computed value automatically becomes the return value, but with Python that isn't the case for regular functions:

```
def times_three(x):
    x*3
```

returns `None`. However, there are also lambda-functions, for which that *is* the case:

```
times_three = lambda x: x*3
times_three(5) #returns 15
```

Answer (score 0):

`None` is the return value of `print0(s)`. When using print the result will just be displayed in the stdout but not returned as result of the function. So the comprehension list evalute the function as `None`. 
Your funtion should instead be:

```
def print0(s):
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you want do it interactively in a one-liner is to use `.join`

```
text = ['28', '43', '6f', '72', '65', '20', '64', '6f', '6d', '70', '65', '64', '29', '0a']

''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in text)
```